# Etymology of *snap, crackle, pop* for higher derivatives of position?

Tags: etymology

The fourth, fifth, and sixth derivatives of position are known as *snap* (or, perhaps more commonly, *jounce*), *crackle*, and *pop*. The latter two of these are probably infrequently used even in a serious mathematics or physics environment, and clearly get their names as humorous allusions to the characters on the Rice Krispies cereal box. Wiktionary, Wikipedia, and etymonline all confirm the existence of the terms, but do not include references to the first usages. I would like to know, if possible, what the earliest source is that used these terms (*crackle* and *pop*).

The references on the Wikipedia page for [pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop_(physics)), are to academic papers published after the year 2000 and reference the terminology as being nonstandard or facetious. They do not, however, refer to earlier uses in other publications.

Answer (score 1):

After digging backwards through citations, I was able to find a reference in the article titled *Some Simple Chaotic Jerk Functions* by J. C. Scott in Am. J. Phys., Vol. 65, No. 6, June 1997 stating:

> The term  ̈x ̈ d4x/dt4 is the time derivative of the jerk, which might be called a ‘‘spasm.’’ It has also been called a ‘‘jounce,’’ a ‘‘sprite,’’ a ‘‘surge,’’ or a ‘‘snap,’’ with its suc- cessive derivatives, ‘‘crackle’’ and ‘‘pop.’’ [17]

With the corresponding citation:

> 17. These terms were suggested by J. Codner, E. Francis, T. Bartels, J. Glass, and W. Jefferys, respectively, in response to a question posed on the USENET sci.physics newsgroup.

Comment: Looks like you may have created two accounts. There is help available on [how to merge accounts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

The following  ***[extract](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/cosmicvariance/2008/07/01/waiter-theres-a-derivative-in-my-cereal/#.VnZgRTT_uK1)*** suggests that  the three terms derive from the well established cereal characters used to convey a  drastic   effect for a higher, unusual, order of derivatives:

> Do we really need a name for the fourth derivative, telling us how the jerk is changing with time? Apparently we do, as it has been denoted the “snap.” I just learned this from this new paper:
>
> ***Cosmic Jerk, Snap and Beyond***
>   Authors: Maciej Dunajski, Gary Gibbons
>
> - *Abstract: We clarify the procedure for expressing the Friedmann equation in terms of directly measurable cosmological scalars constructed out of higher derivatives of the scale factor. We carry out this procedure for pure dust, Chaplygin gas and generalised Chaplygin gas energy-momentum tensors. In each case it leads to a constraint on the scalars thus giving rise to a test of General Relativity. We also discuss a formulation of the Friedmann equation as unparametrised geodesic motion and its connection with the Lagrangian treatment of perfect fluids coupled to gravity.*
>
> The best part is this footnote:
>
> - *The analogous expressions involving 5th and 6th derivatives are known as crackle and pop. **This terminology goes back to a 1932 advertisement of Kellogg’s Rice Crispies which `merrily snap, crackle and pop in a bowl of milk.’***
>
> I suppose there is also some interesting science in there. But now I really want to write a paper that makes use of the 5th time derivative of the scale factor. The words are too delicious to resist.

(blogs.discovermagazine.com)